# Using PReLU layer with tensorflow causes issue but not with other activation functions

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning

I've been trying to make a 1-D ResNet with PReLU and I'm getting the error:

```
ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor.
```

Interestingly enough, if I replace the layers with elu or ReLu layers, the error goes away. This seems counterintuitive to me. Am I doing something wrong or this is an issue with tensorflow?

Here is code that produces the issue:

````py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, BatchNormalization, Activation, Add
from tensorflow.keras.layers import ReLU, PReLU

def resnet_block(inputs, filters, kernel_size, stride):
    # Shortcut connection
    shortcut = inputs
    
    # First convolutional layer
    x = Conv1D(filters, kernel_size, strides=stride, padding='same')(inputs)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = PReLU()(x)
    
    # Second convolutional layer
    x = Conv1D(filters, kernel_size, padding='same')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    
    # Shortcut connection for identity mapping
    if stride > 1 or inputs.shape[-1] != filters:
        shortcut = Conv1D(filters, 1, strides=stride, padding='same')(inputs)
        shortcut = BatchNormalization()(shortcut)
    
    # Add shortcut connection to the main path
    x = Add()([x, shortcut])
    x = PReLU()(x)
    
    return x

# Example usage
input_shape = (None, 1)  # Example input shape
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
x = resnet_block(inputs, filters=64, kernel_size=3, stride=1)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)
model.summary()
model.compile(
    optimizer=Adam(),
    loss="mse",
)
model.fit(x_data, y_data, epochs=5, batch_size=16, validation_split=0.11,shuffle=True,verbose=1)```
````

Comment: Not a solution, but my workaround was to define a prelu layer and call it instead. Here it is:
'class PReLULayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PReLULayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.alpha = self.add_weight(shape=(1,), initializer='zeros', trainable=True)

    def call(self, inputs):
        pos = tf.maximum(0.0, inputs)
        neg = self.alpha * tf.minimum(0.0, inputs)
        return pos + neg'